# Erro criação de arquivo Excel com PHPExcel

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber a forma correta para **alinhar o texto** em todas as colunas; ajustar a largura de todas as colunas; e, também aplicar negrito em intervalos de células.

Da forma que está meu código, ele faz corretamente, porém, gera o erro abaixo:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: : in /home/menqcom1/public_html/php-excel/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 820

```
//Mescla as celulas do titulo
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:D1');

//Alinha o texto a Esquerda
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:E999')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);

// Definir a largura de todas as colunas    
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A:Z')->setWidth(10);

// Formatar o intervalo A2:E3 a itálico
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:E3')->getFont()->setItalic(true);

// Formatar a cor do texto da célula A2 a azul
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:E3')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_BLUE);

// Indicação da criação do ficheiro
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

// Formatar o intervalo A1:F1 a negrito
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Comment: *Your lack of punctuation is disturbing!* Será que não é por que você está formatando as células mescladas junto com as outras não?

Comment: Tente alterar as **aspas simples** por **aspas duplas**

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza consegui resolver. o erro estava pq eu criava o arquivo e depois ainda deixava uma celula em negrito, ou seja, primeiro deveria aplicar estilos, etc pra depois criar o arquivo. obrigado